# How to query Album Unique ID from Genre list using Content Resolver in Android

Tags: android

I am working on Music app and i have a list of songs based on artists,genre,albums,etc. Now what I am trying to get is,unique album ids from a selected Genre.For instance :

if AlbumId1 has five songs in it. Then when i select its genre,5 songs are displayed with same album id. But i want to get only one instance and not 5 instances of same id. How to achieve this.. Please help!

```
List<Track> trackList = new ArrayList<Track>();
String orderBy=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID;
String selection= android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID ;
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external",
                        categoryID), null, selection, null, orderBy);
```

With this query am getting all album ids and few are duplicated as well. I want only unique ids and want to remove all duplicated ids.How to achieve this.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Music app, it is best to let your cursor query for all songs in your device as you will no doubt need that list to show in your library. So if your cursor contains duplicate albums (as several songs will belong to one album), you can solve the problem while actually populating your list.

So if you're using an adapter to populate a listview with distinct album names, just run a loop on your cursor and store only distinct album names in another list, then populate your listview with this list. So it will look something like this:

```
String temp, cval;
        ArrayList<String> albumlist = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
        albumlist.add(temp);
        do
        {
            cval = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
            if(!temp.equals(cval))
            { 
             //Here you can check for it's genre as well, up to you
                    albumlist.add(cval);
                    //Only add the distinct album names to albumlist
                }
                temp = cval;
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

If you still want to query as per genres, you can do that and still use a version of the above code to get distinct album IDs from the songs

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to fetch `Albums` of specific `Genre` from `MediaStore` and this is how I did it :

All you need is to **GROUP BY** albums, to get albums of that particular genre

```
public static CursorLoader getAlbumsByGenre(Context context, int genreId) {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + " IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY (" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;

    return new CursorLoader(context, uri, null, selection, null, null);
}
```